# How to fix error when dropping a Foreign key in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So i managed to set up all my Primary keys without AUTO_INCREMENT, i cannot change a primary key, if it is also a foreign key. So i am trying to remove the foreign keys(and then re-add them after). however it doesnt seem to recognise the Foreign key.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Teacher
    -> DROP FOREIGN KEY Credentials_ID;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'credentials_ID'; check that column/key  exists

mysql> DESCRIBE TEACHER;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Teacher_ID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Class_ID       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Credentials_ID | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Teacher_Name   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see, the Column/Field Credentials_ID exists in the table.

The commands used to make the table Teacher:

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE Teacher(
     -> Teacher_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Class_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Credentials_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Teacher_Name varchar(20),
     -> PRIMARY KEY (Teacher_ID),
     -> FOREIGN KEY (Class_ID) REFERENCES Class(Class_ID),
     -> FOREIGN KEY (Credentials_ID) REFERENCES Credentials(Credentials_ID)
     -> );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `DROP FOREIGN KEY` is the name of the foreign key, not the name of the column(s) in the key. When you created the table you didn't give a name to the FK, so MySQL assigned a name automatically; this default name is derived by concatenating the referencing table, the referenced table, the referenced column names, and `_fk`. If you want to see the name assigned, use

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE Teacher;
```

The result should include:

```
CONSTRAINT `Teacher_Credentials_Credentials_ID_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Credentials_ID`) REFERENCES `Credentials` (`Credentials_ID`)
```

To remove the FK, you need to give this full lname:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Teacher DROP FOREIGN KEY Teacher_Credentials_Credentials_ID_fk;
```

When you're creating the table you can assign a shorter name to your keys to avoid these verbose names, e.g.

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE Teacher(
     -> Teacher_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Class_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Credentials_ID int NOT NULL,
     -> Teacher_Name varchar(20),
     -> PRIMARY KEY (Teacher_ID),
     -> FOREIGN KEY class_ID_fk (Class_ID) REFERENCES Class(Class_ID),
     -> FOREIGN KEY cred_ID_fk (Credentials_ID) REFERENCES Credentials(Credentials_ID)
     -> );
```

Note, however, that foreign key names have to be unique across the whole database, so you can't have two tables with foreign keys to `Credentials(Credentials_ID)` and use the same name `cred_ID_fk` for both of them. This is why the default name includes the table names in them, it ensures that you never get conflicts among these names.